# General solution for $U_{xy}+U_y=e^{-x}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $$U_{xy}+U_y=e^{-x}$$

I followed the substitution mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942092/solving-a-pde-with-mixed-derivatives).

Let $V_x+V=e^{-x}$.  So now we have $(e^{x}V)_x=e^{-x}$.  Integrating w.r.t $x$ we get $$V=-e^{-2x}+e^{-x}c_1(y).$$  Then integrating w.r.t $y$ we get $$U=-ye^{-2x}+ye^{-x}c_1(y)+c_2(x).$$

Is this the correct procedure?

Comment: Why do you ask? You can partial differentiate and check whether you get what you want. Something is probably wrong as differentiating partially your $\;U\;$ I get $\;U_{xy}+U_y=e^{-2x}\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V_x+ V = {\rm e}^{-x}$ implies $({\rm e}^{x}V)_x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$U_{xy}+U_y=e^{-x}$$
Interation relatively to $y$ gives :  $U_x+U=e^{-x}y+f(x)$  any derivable function $f(x)$

Let  $U(x,y)=e^{-x}F(x,y)$
$$U_x+U=e^{-x}F_x=e^{-x}y+f(x)$$
$$F_x=y+e^xf(x)=y+g(x)$$
Integration relatively to $x$ gives :  $F=xy+G(x)+h(y)$  any derivable functions $G$ and $h$
$$U(x,y)=e^{-x}\left(xy+G(x)+h(y)\right)$$
or $$U(x,y)=e^{-x}\left(xy+h(y)\right)+H(x)$$
where $h$ and $H$ are any derivable functions.